# constexpr are not getting evaluated properly for LLVM compiler

Tags: c++, llvm, constexpr

I am compiling below code on VS compiler and LLVM compiler and have noticed that LLVM compiler does not evaluate constexpr properly .

So below extract from below example behaves differently in LLVM and VS compiler

```cpp
template <TUInt64 TWAppType>
bool
TWApplicationTemplate<TWAppType>::InternalInitialize ()
{
    if constexpr (TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread (TWAppType)) {
        static_assert(0, "TRUE evaluated");
        extern bool TWClientMain ();
    }
    return true;
}
```

In case of LLVM compiler this expression (constexpr (TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread (TWAppType)) returns true but for VS it returns false at compile time (VS behavior is correct behaviour)

//Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int TWApp_Client_As_Background_Thread = 8192;

constexpr bool TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread(int pTWAppType) {
  return ((pTWAppType & TWApp_Client_As_Background_Thread) != 0);
}

typedef unsigned _int64 TUInt64;

template <TUInt64 TWAppType>
class TWApplicationTemplate {
 public:
  static bool TWApplicationInitialize();

 private:
  static bool InternalInitialize();
};

template <TUInt64 TWAppType>
bool TWApplicationTemplate<TWAppType>::TWApplicationInitialize() {
  return InternalInitialize();
}

template <TUInt64 TWAppType>
bool TWApplicationTemplate<TWAppType>::InternalInitialize() {
  if constexpr (TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread(TWAppType)) {
    static_assert(0, "TRUE evaluated");
    extern bool TWClientMain();
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int pArgc, char* pArgv[]) {
  constexpr int TVal = 987080;

  TWApplicationTemplate<TVal> t1;
  t1.TWApplicationInitialize();
  return 0;
}

bool TWClientMain() {
  std::cout << "Executing TWClientMain " << std::endl;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Ideally to me on both LLVM and VS 2019 compiler it should behaves same.  Any help to find is causing LLVM to not behave properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel like formatting code is not as difficult a task as it is made to appear.

Answer (score 1):

> In case of LLVM compiler this expression (constexpr (TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread (TWAppType)) returns true but for VS it returns false at compile time (VS behavior is correct behaviour)

But does it really? I think your assumption is incorrect. I think both LLVM and MSVC evaluates to false.

Then you'll say:

> But... but... LLVM prints `TRUE evaluated`, how could this be?

This is because you have ill formed code.

This line is not valid C++:

```
static_assert(0, "TRUE evaluated");
```

The standard says, at [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8) (emphasis mine):

> **The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.**
> [*Note:* Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way.
> — *end note*]
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - **no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement** within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
> - [...]

Since there cannot exist a specialization of the template which `static_assert(0, "...")` is valid, the compiler can issue a diagnostic.

And since no diagnostic is required, both compiler are right, and even though with MSVC it works, your program is still ill formed.

As you can see, this is very much like a template. You could have a template that you never instantiate and never ends up in your binary, but the compiler still check for the validity of the code. If it can prove ahead of time that the code cannot be well formed, then it may issue a diagnostic.

The same goes for the discarded part of a constexpr if. The discarded part is not compiled, but it is *not* a token soup: the compiler may check that the code is not plainly ill formed. If you call a function that don't exist or write `static_assert(false)`, then the compiler may issue a diagnostic, and it is right to do so, even if it's in the discarded part of a constexpr if.

Comment: I agree that static_assert(0,"....") is ill formed. What I was trying to ask is below if constexpr evaluation 
 `if constexpr (TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread(TWAppType)) { 
static_assert(0, "TRUE evaluated"); extern bool TWClientMain(); }`

Even though this function TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread(TWAppType) evaluates to false still static_assert code is included. My understanding was that if function TWAppClientAsBackgroundThread(TWAppType) evaluates  false on compile time , below code would be discarded and would not even compiled.

Comment: Even though if I use code like below 
`
 if constexpr(false)
{
   extern int abc();
}
`
still I cam see if declares abc . I thought it would discard extern declaration of abc all together.

Comment: Well, it's the same thing with a never used template. `template<typename T> void f() { abc(); }` Even if you never instantiate the template and the code is not compiled, the compiler still check for `abc` to exist. If no instantiation of the template exist for the code to be valid, then the code is ill formed NDR. The very same goes for the discarded part of a constexpr if.

Comment: Well my understanding of constexpr was wrong. constexpr are not like #if def rather its path to chose for running the application. Though all paths of constexpr should be valid code as they will get compiled

Comment: @user3409976 not exactly, but very close. There cannot be an invalid path that is invalid for any template instantiation. If there is no way that the else branch is valid for any template instantiation, the compiler can issue a diagnostic. This is why you can still have expressions in the else branch that wouldn't compile for some instantiations.